# Next palindrome date and time

Tags: mathematics

Date and time is formatted as "hh:mm:ss DD:MM:YY", where hh is a 24 hour clock, mm are minutes, ss are seconds, DD are days, MM are months and YY are the last two digits of the year. All terms can have leading zeroes. A palindrome date and time is one that reads the same forwards and backwards. When is the next such date and time?

**Bonus question:** When was the previous such date and time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next palindrome date/time will be

> 02:10:03 30:01:20 - 2:10:03 on 30th of January 2020

This must be the next one, since

> Today's date is 27:01:20, which backwards is 02:10:72, which is an invalid number of seconds. So keep increasing until it's valid.

The previous palindrome date/time was

> 02:10:52 25:01:20 - 2:10:52 on 25th January 2020

Just for completeness

> All dates are palindromic if the second digit of the day and month are both less than or equal to 5, and the year is represented as one of
> 00, 01, 02, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 30, 31, 32, 40, 41, 50, 51, 60, 61, 70, 71, 80, 81, 90, 91
>  The time can always be worked out from the date.